# REGEX with PHP (what am I doing wrong?)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Let's say I want to place the **bold content** into a variable called *$question_text*.

1} **What color is the sky:

A) Answer A

B) Answer B

C) Answer C**

Answer: A

How do I use preg_match to do that?

I tried:

```
if(preg_match("#}(.*)#", $question, $question_match))
{
    //Extract the question text
    $question_text = trim($question_match[1]);
```

But it only gives me the first line: **What color is the sky: **

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are you trying to return?

Comment: And what of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50458152/preg-match-with-regex

Comment: I apologize, I though someone had deleted it, I could find it in my logs.

Comment: I'm trying to return what's bolded:

Comment: You are only matching lines that contain `}`, so of course the others don't match.

Comment: `preg_match` only gives 1 match. `preg_match_all` is for multiple. See https://regex101.com/r/zLYd6S/2/ vs https://regex101.com/r/zLYd6S/1/, assuming you correct the regex. Also you could just explode on new lines. You really aren't using regex power here.

Comment: Can you recommend an answer for me, as to how I'd store what's in bold in a variable? By the way, who keeps down-voting my posts?!

Comment: You could use dot-all perhaps `#(?s)}(.*)#` which would put your question and answers in one array, although I'm not sure that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Where does `bold content` come from? How do you know where to end? We need more parameters to help.

Comment: Also, practice the regex here: https://regexr.com/

Comment: I'L'I is correct! Except, I want it not to include everything after and including **Answer:**

Comment: `Answer:` is not in bold in your question. Please take time to format your question so it has all information. We are 11 comments in and finding new requirements. Maybe `\d}[\S\s]+?Answer: [A-Z]` I suspect there are more requirements though.

Comment: with every comment you add, its less clear what you actually want.

Comment: I want what's in **bold** to be placed in _$question_text_. Notice Answer: ... is not in bold.

Comment: I want it **not**

Answer (score -1):

```
#(?s)}(.*)+?Answer: [A-Z]#
```

Worked for me!